# Get PID of browser started by Selenium (in java)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pid

Is it possible to get the PID of the browser that is started by Selenium Webdriver.

This would have to be in Java, as that is how I run webdriver. Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752512/get-pid-of-browser-launched-by-selenium 
This link should answer ur question

Comment: I've seen it, but I'm unable to get this into my java program :(

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly, you would have get the list of processes currently running and filter it down.

There is no special attributes or features that Selenium uses to launch a browser. Therefore, if you are running an instance of that browser that was launched **manually**, you will get that too. That is to say that if you have two instances of Firefox, one that Selenium launched and is doing it's testing on, and one of your own Firefox sessions, then you are going to have **both** in the filtered list, there is **no way at all** to tell them apart.

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java). Use this code to get all currently running processes. Filter it down to the browser you are trying to get.

If you explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this, we may be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Well sometimes IE fails to close, so I have to kill it. It is stuck at "do you want to close this page". Anyway, I have worked around it by listing all PIDs from the browser I'm starting, and after my tests closing those that were not running before my test.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box, selenium does not expose driver process id or Browser hwnd but it is possible. Below is the logic to get hwnd

When driver is initialized, get the url for hub and extract the port number
From port number, find the process id which is using this port for listening, ie. PID of driver
After navigation, from all instances of iexplore find the parent PID matches the pid of driver, i.e browser pid.
Get the Hwnd of browser pid once browser hwnd is found , you can use win32 api to bring selenium to foreground.
its not possible to post full code here, the full working solution (C#) to bring browser in front is on my blog

http://www.pixytech.com/rajnish/2016/09/selenium-webdriver-get-browser-hwnd/