# How to bring browser to front using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, awtrobot

I've a test where it handles login system popup using `Robot` of Java. But because of some issues, other applications or browser instance come to front and Robot could not perform actions on system popup of Windows.

Hence before interacting with system popup using `Robot`, I want to bring that browser to front on machine. I tried following but it did not help -

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

Could you please suggest how I can bring it to the front?

Comment: Possible solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front

Comment: Have you tried with maximize window and switch to window options? If that does not work then you can use the PID of the browser instance and switch the focus.

Comment: @supputuri, maximizing window and switching to window did not help. I looked in Java api of Selenium and googled but could not found how to get PID of browser. However for python there is a solution  here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752512/get-pid-of-browser-launched-by-selenium. Please let me know if  you know same for Java.