# How to get PID of a browser instance using Selenium WebDriver + Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

To [bring browser to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478471/how-to-bring-browser-to-front-using-selenium-webdriver), as per one of comments I need to get PID of browser. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752512/get-pid-of-browser-launched-by-selenium) helps to get PID but that is for Python. Is there any way, I can get PID of browser using Selenium WebDriver + Java?

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the PID of *Firefox Browser* initiated and controlled by [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) you can use `getCapabilities()` method and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;

  import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

  public class PID_Firefox_Java {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
          System.out.println("moz:processID value is : "+cap.getCapability("moz:processID"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  moz:processID value is : 4576
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer! It works for Firefox but could not find similar for Chrome. I'm looking for generic solution which will work across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it directly possible for Chrome as @DebanjanB posted for Firefox. You can use below code for now to achieve that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(new Example().getProcessId("firefox"));
}


public String getProcessId(String browserName) throws IOException {
    int port = 0;
    WebDriver driver;


    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        GeckoDriverService service = GeckoDriverService.createDefaultService();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        port = service.getUrl().getPort();


    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
        port = service.getUrl().getPort();

    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i :" + port).getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(String.valueOf(port)) && line.contains("LISTEN")) {
            set.add(line.split(" ")[1]);
        }
    }
    return set.iterator().next();
}
```

**UPDATED:**

For windows, command is different. So need to make some tweaks in above code.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -aon | find \""+ port+"\"").getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(String.valueOf(port)) && line.contains("LISTEN")) {
        String s[]=line.split(" ");
        set.add(s[s.length-1]);
    }
}
return set.iterator().next();
```

> **Note:** The command i passed to get PID is used on Mac. Please change it as per OS in case it doesn't work.

Comment: This is resulting into error - `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lsof": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. I'm working on Windows machine. Can you please suggest how to resolve this? What is equivalent of it?

Comment: @TDHM, if you are using windows then it must be a windows command to get a process id using port number. refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215252/5097027

Comment: This returns port correctly but no value is returned for executed command and hence `set.iterator().next();` results into `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. However same command manually executed gives correct result.

Comment: @TDHM https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204920/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-59484118-how-to-get-pid-of-a-browser-instance

Comment: `lsof` takes a long time to run, would it be possible to use something more instantaneous, such as `ps`?